# Prove that $detA=a_{0}$ and $trA=(-1)^{n-1}a_{n-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $w(\lambda)=(-1)^{n}\lambda^{n}+a_{n-1} \lambda^{n-1}+...+a_{1}\lambda +a_{0}$ which is characteristic polynomial of $A \in M_{nxn}(K)$. Prove that:
> (a) $detA=a_{0}$
> (b) $trA=(-1)^{n-1}a_{n-1}$.

I know that $w(\lambda)=det(A-\lambda I)=det\begin{bmatrix} b_{1}-\lambda &  &  &  \\  & b_{2}-\lambda &  &  \\  &  & \dots &  \\  &  &  & b_{n}-\lambda \end{bmatrix}$ where empty fields in this matrix represent for me the presence of the same values as the matrix $ A $ which is just on the diagonal values are changing (in $A$ I have $b_{1},...b_{n}$ on the diagonal).
Unfortuately I don't know how to combine this fact with $w(\lambda)=(-1)^{n}\lambda^{n}+a_{n-1} \lambda^{n-1}+...+a_{1}\lambda +a_{0}$ and prove (a) and (b) because I think I should count $ w (\lambda) $ "from the back" to receive $det(A-\lambda I)$ and it is difficult for me and I suspect that there is a better way.
Can you help me with it?

Comment: See the material following directly after the proof of Proposition 2.39 in [Anthony W. Knapp, *Basic Algebra*, digital 2nd edition](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~aknapp/download/b2-alg-inside.pdf). He works with $\det\left(\lambda I - A\right)$ instead of $\det\left(A - \lambda I\right)$, but this is just a factor of $\left(-1\right)^n$ apart.

Comment: Or see Corollaries 2.4 **(b)** and 2.32 in [my *The trace Cayley-Hamilton theorem*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/trach.pdf) (note that I take a giant detour to Corollary 2.32 in order to avoid handwaving).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the determinant, one can simply plug $0$ as the value of $\lambda$, and it follows directly from the definition that $\det A=w(0)=a_0$.

For the trace, consider the following. The determinant of $A-\lambda I$ has $n!$ terms. How many of them possess $\lambda^{n-1}$? Only $1$: the diagonal product. And the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$ in this term is exactly $(-1)^{n-1}(b_1+...+b_n)$.

Comment: Please change $(-1)^{n-!}$ into $(-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Leaning Why can I simply plug $0$ as the value of $\lambda$ if $\lambda$ is own value of $A$ and I don't know it?

Comment: @MP3129 because $w(\lambda)$ is defined to be the value of $\det(A-\lambda I)$, hence $w(0)$ should be equal to $\det(A-o)=\det A$. 

In case you consider $A-\lambda I$ as a matrix of coefficients in $k[\lambda]$, then there exists a natural $0$-evaluation morphism from $k[\lambda]$ to $k$, which sent $w(\lambda)$ to its $a_0$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

If your initial matrix $ A $ is diagonal, then

$$w(\lambda)=(b_1-\lambda)(b_2-\lambda)...(b_n-\lambda)$$

the constant coefficient is

$$a_0=b_1b_2...b_n=det(A)$$

the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$
is

$$b_1(-1)^{n-1}+b_2(-1)^{n-1}+...$$

Comment: Why can you assume that $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: @MP3129 I said if your matrix is...

Comment: Ok, but then I should also consider the case when $ A $ is not diagonal?